# Is it possible to change your username?

Tags: support, profile-page, display-names, user-information

I created a Stack Overflow account using my Gmail account. I would now like to change the username. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Ask @welbog, I mean, @welboug, wait, I mean @susan. Rats, I mean @www.biglaser.net.

Comment: Hey you forgot "welbo_g"!

Comment: @Troggy: shut the welbog up! The first rule about welb_g, you don't talk about welb_g

Comment: No, you only have to censor the british version. Welbo_g. ;)

Comment: There was another "susan ...something..." in there, too, but it was too long to remember.

Comment: That'd be [Susan Papadismgaogenabhieanae](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26518/131713).

Comment: Please help! I don't know how to change my network username (global name). I've change the name on the sites, but the global name remains the same.

Answer (score 41):

- Click on your name in the top right
- Click on the tab "Edit Profile & Settings"
- Edit "Display name" field
- Complete your profile and earn an autobiographer badge in the process.

<sub>I am leaving this here since I actually went through the effort of answering the question</sub>

Answer (score 9):

Click on your username at the top of the page. Just to the left of the gray user-information area, you will see a link to 'edit'. There you can change your username.

Answer (score 7):

The details in the UI may have changed a bit since the previous answers were posted, but they're still mostly right.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I swear when I clicked my user name (several times) only a popup window appeared with my activity/privileges/log out thing. It was about 30 minutes ago. But now it is working differently, opens my profile page.

Comment: Man you're old. Or young. Is that big Endian or small Endian?